# Django ORM messes related objects with prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-polymorphic

I experience very weird behaviour of `prefetch_related` call. Here is the illustration:

```
# First define two sketch models, just for convenience of the further talk.

class Secondary(models.Model):
    pass

class Primary(models.Model):
    secondaries = models.ManyToManyField(Secondary)

# Just to make clear, EVERY Primary object in my system has at least one
# related Secondary object.

# Now prepare a query.

primaries = Primary.objects.filter(...)\
                           .order_by(...)\
                           .prefetch_related('secondary')

# Iterating:

for primary in primaries:
    if not primary.secondaries.all():
        # So we have found an object that is said to not have
        # any relatives.  Re-query this particular object.
        # This part is hit in my code, although it should not.
        primary = Primary.objects.get(pk=primary.pk)
    for secondary in primary.secondaries.all():
        # Voila, there are relatives!
        # This part was not hit for some objects until I added
        # the re-query part above.
        pass
```

Just to make clear, there are no `Primary` objects in my system that do not have related `Secondary` objects, but still the code above hits the re-query part for some of them (always the same ones), and re-querying fetches the secondaries that were missing.  And what is even more weird, I can see that some Primaries get repeating Secondaries in their `secondaries.all()`—the overall impression is that ORM connects some sets of Secondaries to wrong Primaries by mistake.

What could be wrong?  Is that some bug of Django, or of the database?

I use Django 1.10.5, psycopg2 2.7.3, and Postgres 9.6.

**Update:** I have found that the issue is even worse: sometimes the ORM returns incomplete lists of related objects, so my workaround explained above doesn't help.  We had to remove the prefetch_related call because obviously we cannot rely on data that it returns.

**Update 2:** as Daniel asked in comments, here are some real SQL queries (although not from the system where we experienced the problem). `backend_build` is the "primary" model, and there are several "secondary" models: `backend_buildproblem`, `backend_sanityproblem`, and `backend_runproblem`—we use django_polymorphic for them, the base model is `backend_problem`.

The Python code looks like this:

```
builds = Build.objects.filter(
    branch__active=True,
    type__active=True,
    finish_timestamp__gt=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=10))\
 .order_by('-finish_timestamp')\
 .prefetch_related('problems')

for build in builds:
  for problem in build.problems.all():
    print problem.id  # just a stub code to use results of the query.
```

And here are the resulting SQL queries:

```
SELECT "backend_build"."teamcity_id", "backend_build"."status", "backend_build"."finish_timestamp", "backend_build"."type_id", "backend_build"."branch_id", "backend_build"."revision"
  FROM "backend_build"
  INNER JOIN "backend_buildtype" ON ("backend_build"."type_id" = "backend_buildtype"."id")
  INNER JOIN "backend_branch" ON ("backend_build"."branch_id" = "backend_branch"."id")
  WHERE ("backend_build"."finish_timestamp" > \'2017-08-18T06:35:21.322000+00:00\'::timestamptz AND "backend_buildtype"."active" = true AND "backend_branch"."active" = true)
  ORDER BY "backend_build"."finish_timestamp" DESC 

SELECT "backend_problem"."id", "backend_problem"."polymorphic_ctype_id", "backend_problem"."generic_type", "backend_problem"."startrack_id", "backend_problem"."useful", "backend_problem"."status", "backend_problem"."summary"
  FROM "backend_problem"
  INNER JOIN "backend_build_problems" ON ("backend_problem"."id" = "backend_build_problems"."problem_id")
  WHERE "backend_build_problems"."build_id" = 18984809

SELECT "backend_problem"."id", "backend_problem"."polymorphic_ctype_id", "backend_problem"."generic_type", "backend_problem"."startrack_id", "backend_problem"."useful", "backend_problem"."status", "backend_problem"."summary", "backend_sanityproblem"."problem_ptr_id", "backend_sanityproblem"."code", "backend_sanityproblem"."latest_occurred"
  FROM "backend_sanityproblem"
  INNER JOIN "backend_problem" ON ("backend_sanityproblem"."problem_ptr_id" = "backend_problem"."id")
  WHERE "backend_sanityproblem"."problem_ptr_id" IN (9251, 9252, 9253, 9254, 9255, 9256, 9257, 9259, 9261, 9262, 9263, 9264, 9268, 9269, 9270, 9271, 9272, 9273, 9274, 9275, 9276, 9277, 9280, 9283, 9285, 9287, 9290, 9293, 9294, 9295, 9297, 9302, 9303, 9304, 9306, 9307, 9309, 9312, 9313, 9314, 9316, 9317, 9319, 9321, 9322, 9062, 9063, 9066, 9068, 9092, 9107, 9109, 9112, 9648, 9649, 9650, 9651, 9652, 9653, 9654, 9655, 9656, 9657, 9658, 9659, 9660, 9661, 9662, 9663, 9664, 9665, 9666, 9667, 9668, 9669, 9670, 9671, 9672, 9673, 9674, 9675, 9676, 9677, 9678, 9679, 9680, 9681, 9682, 9683, 9684, 9685, 9686, 9687, 9688, 9689, 9690, 9691, 9692, 9693, 9694)

SELECT "backend_problem"."id", "backend_problem"."polymorphic_ctype_id", "backend_problem"."generic_type", "backend_problem"."startrack_id", "backend_problem"."useful", "backend_problem"."status", "backend_problem"."summary", "backend_sanityproblem"."problem_ptr_id", "backend_sanityproblem"."code", "backend_sanityproblem"."latest_occurred"
  FROM "backend_sanityproblem"
  INNER JOIN "backend_problem" ON ("backend_sanityproblem"."problem_ptr_id" = "backend_problem"."id")
  WHERE "backend_sanityproblem"."problem_ptr_id" IN (9344, 9345, 9488, 9489, 9508, 9509, 9510, 9511, 9512, 9513, 9399, 9401, 9402, 9403, 9426, 9436, 9572, 9573, 9574, 9575, 9330, 9337, 9338, 9339, 9340, 9341, 9342)

SELECT "backend_problem"."id", "backend_problem"."polymorphic_ctype_id", "backend_problem"."generic_type", "backend_problem"."startrack_id", "backend_problem"."useful", "backend_problem"."status", "backend_problem"."summary"
  FROM "backend_problem"
  INNER JOIN "backend_build_problems" ON ("backend_problem"."id" = "backend_build_problems"."problem_id")
  WHERE "backend_build_problems"."build_id" = 18944441

SELECT "backend_problem"."id", "backend_problem"."polymorphic_ctype_id", "backend_problem"."generic_type", "backend_problem"."startrack_id", "backend_problem"."useful", "backend_problem"."status", "backend_problem"."summary", "backend_buildproblem"."problem_ptr_id", "backend_buildproblem"."stage"
  FROM "backend_buildproblem"
  INNER JOIN "backend_problem" ON ("backend_buildproblem"."problem_ptr_id" = "backend_problem"."id")
  WHERE "backend_buildproblem"."problem_ptr_id" IN (9600)

SELECT "backend_problem"."id", "backend_problem"."polymorphic_ctype_id", "backend_problem"."generic_type", "backend_problem"."startrack_id", "backend_problem"."useful", "backend_problem"."status", "backend_problem"."summary"
  FROM "backend_problem"
  INNER JOIN "backend_build_problems" ON ("backend_problem"."id" = "backend_build_problems"."problem_id")
  WHERE "backend_build_problems"."build_id" = 18944330
```

There are more queries like these, I omit them here.  It seems clear from the above that the system ritst queries the primary model, and then requests relations for each primary object, and it takes their polymorphic types into account.

Comment: Can you post the resulting SQL queries?

Comment: @DanielHepper sure I can, but how to do that so the info would be useful?  The raw connection.queries contains real IDs from my DB, and of course the queries reflect my real DB shema which differs from what I explained above, so I would need to explain it as well.  Could you advise on what particular parts are you interested in?

Comment: If the table names are not sensitive, I'd just post the full queries and explain which models are Primary and Secondary. Maybe shorten the list of ids if it is too long.

Comment: @DanielHepper I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue stems from the fact that you have multiple secondary models with the same base model. There is probably an internal cache that gets overwritten with each query. Try limiting the `prefetch_related` statement to the `problems` model:

```
.prefetch_related('problems')
```

Or maybe it is related to [this issue with django-polymorphic](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/issues/68)?

Comment: Limiting the `prefetch_related` to the `problems` model doesn't help.  In fact, I had that in my code, and it didn't work.  The issue woth django-polymorphic seems to be related indeed.  Thanks!